# Generate a random number in ruby with some conditions

Tags: ruby, numbers

I have no idea of how to proceed, I've been learning ruby for just one week. I thought I'd create an array filled by an external source, such as a database and forbid these elements inside to be picked up by the script. Is it possible? I just want to have a general idea of how creating such script.

Comment: But what *are* the conditions ?

Comment: Some numbers inside an array shall not be picked up.

Comment: Can you expand on what you are trying to do? What have you tried so far? Can you post some code showing the area that you are having a problem with?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean some thing like this?

```
forbidden_numbers = [ 5 , 6 , 3 , 4]
new_number = loop do
  tmp_number = rand 1_000_000
  break tmp_number unless forbidden_numbers.include?(tmp_number)
end

puts new_number
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have two choices:

1. Remove the ineligible elements, then choose one at random:

```
   arr.reject {...}.sample
```

2. Choose an element at random. If it is disallowed, repeat, continuing until a valid element is found:

```
   until (n=arr.sample) && ok?(n) end
   n
```

Without additional information we cannot say which approach is best in this case.